# can Chrome option page access indexedDB created by my background script?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, indexeddb

I am working on a chrome extension, and really want to have my chrome option page access the data in the IndexedDB, but there seems no support for this?

Error as:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transaction' of undefined option.js:42

```
     var request = indexedDB.open(DB_NAME, DB_VERSION);
    //console.log(request); /* The created indexedDB can be checked */

    request.onsuccess = function (evt) {
        console.log("Database Open Successfully: " + evt);
        db = this.result;

        /* Get the initialised logIndex*/
        var storeLog = db.transaction(DB_STORE1, 'readonly').objectStore(DB_STORE1); 
        var req = storeLog.openCursor(null, 'prev');

        req.onsuccess = function (evt) {
             console.log("Inner Successfully");
        }
        req.onerror = function(evt){
             console.error("Inner error" + evt.target.errorCode);
        }
    };

    request.onerror = function (evt) {
        console.error("Database Error: " + evt.target.errorCode);
    };
```

want to know whether it is possible to access the IndexedDB in the "chrome option_page"

Comment: Without your code, no way to understand what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Try using `db = evt.target.result;` instead.

Comment: Thanks. But still not working. Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': One of the specified object stores was not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short answer to your *stated* question is "yes, IndexedDB is fully supported in extension pages". The fact that your `request.onsuccess` is fired is sufficient evidence to that.

It seems like your problems are not specific to Chrome Extensions; I suggest that you look at some IndexedDB tutorials [like this one](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/) to debug your code.

Note that you might need to request `"unlimitedStorage"` permission in the manifest to store large amounts of data.